# Does $f(x)=x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ satisfy the relation $f(x)+f(y)−2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=O\left(\left|x−y\right|^2\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does $f(x)=x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$,  $x\in(0,1)$ satisfy the relation $f(x)+f(y)−2f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)=O\left(\left|x−y\right|^2\right)$?

Answer (score 2):

NO. Let $x=t+d, y=t-d$, then we shall consider $f(t+d)+f(t-d)-2f(t)=O(d^2)$.

Note that
$$\lim_{d\to 0}\frac{f(t+d)+f(t-d)-2f(t)}{d^2}=f''(t),$$
so basically we need $f''$ is bounded in $(0,1)$, by calculation you will find this is not the case.